# What does $w_{ni}$ mean in the weighted nearest neighbour classifier?

Tags: classification, k-nearest-neighbour, weighted-mean

Wiki gives this [definition of KNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm)

> In pattern recognition, the k-nearest neighbors algorithm (k-NN) is a
>   non-parametric method used for classification and regression. In both
>   cases, the input consists of the k closest training examples in the
>   feature space. The output depends on whether k-NN is used for
>   classification or regression:
>
> - In k-NN classification, the output is a class membership. An object    is classified by a plurality vote of its neighbors, with the object
>     being assigned to the class most common among its k nearest neighbors 
>     (k is a positive integer, typically small). If k = 1, then the object 
>     is simply assigned to the class of that single nearest neighbor.
> - In k-NN regression, the output is the property value for the object.    This value is the average of the values of k nearest
>     neighbors.

and this [explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm#The_weighted_nearest_neighbour_classifier) about "The weighted nearest neighbour classifier"

> The k-nearest neighbour classifier can be viewed as assigning the k
>   nearest neighbours a weight 1/k and all others 0 weight. This can be
>   generalised to weighted nearest neighbour classifiers. That is, where
>   the ith nearest neighbour is assigned a weight ${\displaystyle
> > w_{ni}}$, with ${\displaystyle \sum _{i=1}^{n}w_{ni}=1}$. An analogous
>   result on the strong consistency of weighted nearest neighbour
>   classifiers also holds.

this $w_{ni}$ confuses me a lot.

taking the [iris dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/iris) as the example, there are 150 data points, if we choose k=50, are there top 50 neighbours, each of which has a 1/50 weight, and the other 100 data points 0 weight.

if it is, $w_i = 1/50$ where $i=1, 2, ..., 50$.

so, what does $w_{ni}$ mean?

Assume $_{1}$ represents the nearest neighbor, $_{2}$ represents the second nearest neighbor, what does "n" in $_{i}$=1/50 mean? Does $_{11}$mean the first example weights 1/50 to first class, say, Iris Setosa?

Answer (score 1):

In weighted nearest neighbour, all of the points in the dataset have a contribution, which is quantified by $w_{ni}$ in your references. So, in this version, there is no top $k$. Every point in the dataset has a saying on the outcome. And, KNN can also be considered as a special case of weighted NN where $w_{ni}=1/k$ when $1\leq i\leq k$, and $0$ otherwise. In regression, these weights can be directly incorporated to the outcome, i.e. $$\hat{y}=\sum_{i=1}^nw_{ni}y_i$$
But in classification, you'll count votes together with weights, i.e. the cumulative vote for class $m$ is calculated as follows: $$c_m=\sum_{i=1}^nw_{ni}\underbrace{\mathbf{1}[y_i=m]}_{\text{indicator function}}=\sum_{y_i=m}w_{ni}$$
In the end, you'll compare the votes on classes. And, decide the class with the highest vote.

Taking your example, i.e. the iris dataset, and a KNN with $k=50$, we have $w_{ni}=1/50$ for $1\leq i \leq 50$, as you noted. So, the top $50$ nearest neighbors have equal *vote* on the outcome. Iris dataset has three classes, so you'll calculate $c_1,c_2,c_3$ and choose the one with the highest value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Assume $w_{n1}$ represents the nearest neighbor, $w_{n2}$ represents the second nearest neighbor, what does "n" in $w_{ni}=1/50$ mean? What does $w_{11}$ mean the first example weights 1/50 to first class, say, Iris Setosa?